# How to replace ec2 image with other ec2 instance image?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ec2-ami

i have two ec2 instances. Names are server1 and server2
Server1 and server2 have its own images and running. Now i want to replace server2 image with server1 image ?

How i can do this without changing ip address, is there any way?

Comment: _WHY_ do you wish to do this? What do you mean by "replace server2 image with server1 image" -- what should happen with server1, should it keep running? Why not just terminate server2 and launch a new instance with the same private IP address? If you tell us more about what you are trying to accomplish and _why_, we might be able to offer better advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally if you depend on the ip address never changing, you would assign an elastic-ip to the ec2 instance, then at any point you could start another instance, configure it however you want, and when you are ready to cutover, just re-assign the IP address.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html

Answer (score 0):

From what I remember you can shut down both machines and detach their hard drives and re-attach them the other way around (as /dev/xvda).

I would recommend setting an Elastic IP otherwise there's no guarantee you'll get the same Public IP after restarting.

Comment: but ip address will be changed if i shutdown the machine

Comment: Exactly, this is why I recommended setting en Elastic IP, this way it will be changed once but it will remain the same after restart.